# Vue.js - loop through nested array only x times

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nested-loops

unfortunately I am stuck with a problem in vue.js. I would like to step through a nested array with v-for, but only get 15 entries from it.

With this execution I get all entries in the array which contains objects.

```
<CardDashboard
    v-for="(item, i) in this.productionList.rows"
    :key="i"
    :productionData="item"
/>
```

I have tried other methods, such as .slice and also v-for in v-for. Unfortunately both of these approaches do not work on the nested array.

Does anyone know how to get only a certain number of entries from a nested array?

Comment: Make a `shorterProductionList` `computed` property with `this.productionList.rows.slice(15)` and `v-for` on that brand new one. Also, don't use the index as a key.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
computed: {
 getProductionListRowsSlice() {
  return this.productionList.rows.slice(15);
 }
}
```

```
<CardDashboard
    v-for="(item, i) in getProductionListSlice"
    :key="i"
    :productionData="item"
/>
```

Comment: Looks like something I could write. Also, don't use the index in a `v-for` as I mentionned.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the example :) unfortunately it doesnt work.

is it possible that it is the json itself? the output looks like this:
{
"total": 123,
"rows": [
{
"x": 123,
"y": 456,
"z": 789,
},
{
"x": 123,
"y": 456,
"z": 789,
}
]
}